# TypeError: _get_loc_req() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given) - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def _get_loc_req(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    """Get if a field is required or not by a Localization
    @param uid: Integer value of the user
    """
    context = context or {}
    res = True
    ru_brw = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(
        cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    rc_obj = self.pool.get('res.company')
    rc_brw = rc_obj.browse(cr, uid, ru_brw.company_id.id, context=context)

    if rc_brw.country_id and rc_brw.country_id.code == 'VE' and \
            rc_brw.printer_fiscal:
        res = False
    return res
```

Every time I click on the button which calls for this function, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 342, in create
invoice = super(AccountInvoice, self.with_context(mail_create_nolog=True)).create(vals)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 227, in create
thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3778, in create
vals = self._add_missing_default_values(vals)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1618, in _add_missing_default_values
defaults = self.default_get(list(missing_defaults))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/invoice.py", line 61, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_loc_req(),
TypeError: _get_loc_req() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

As I've said, I'm migrating some modules from v8 to v10 community, should I also change the arguments? Besides adding the correct decorator?

The decorator `@api.multi` was added by me, since this method operates  on records, but maybe it is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button methods should look like:

```py
@api.multi
def my_method(self):
    # my logic
    return True
```

There is no need to handle database cursor, record ids, user id and context "manually" anymore with the new API.

---

With old API your method should have failed too or the context was filled with ids. It should've looked like:

```py
def _get_loc_req(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
```

You have just missed the `ids`.

Comment: THAT was something I needed to understand in new API, lol, awesome! Thank You very much